# Audio to text: speech recognition but with an audio file instead of microphone input

Tags: javascript, audio, speech-recognition

I'm wondering if I could use JavaScript to automatically align wrongly timed subtitle files with a corresponding audio or video track.

I know about the speech recognition API, which might be helpful, but I don't know of any way to pipe an audio stream into it, instead of microphone input. The documentation on MDN makes me think this might be possible, but who knows?

> which provides the ability to recognize voice context from an audio
>   input (normally via the device's default speech recognition service)
>   and respond appropriately

To be clear: I'm looking for a JavaScript-only solution. I don't want to reroute input and output streams on the device itself.

Comment: Hi mate, have you had any luck with that?

Comment: Nope I did not..

Comment: I'm also wondering for it!